# How to insert a NSString into a NSMutableString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I have a NSMutableString where i need to insert another NSString at two places. My NSMutableString is

```
NSMutableString *webServiceLinkWithResponses = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://lmsstaging.2xprime.com/services/ParticipantService.cfc?method=setVideoExamResults&student_id=10082&course_id=VRT_TRA&lesson=904&examtype=r&question_num=&ansValue="];
```

I need to insert one String(One) after "question_num=" and another string(One) after "ansValue=" so my final string should be like

[http://lmsstaging.com/services/ParticipantService.cfc?method=setVideoExamResults&student_id=10082&course_id=VRT_TRA&lesson=904&examtype=r&question_num=One&ansValue=One](http://lmsstaging.2xprime.com/services/ParticipantService.cfc?method=setVideoExamResults&student_id=10082&course_id=VRT_TRA&lesson=904&examtype=r&question_num=One&ansValue=One)

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSMutableString *webServiceLinkWithResponses = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://lmsstaging.2xprime.com/services/ParticipantService.cfc?method=setVideoExamResults&student_id=10082&course_id=VRT_TRA&lesson=904&examtype=r&question_num=%@&ansValue=%@",yourFirstString,yourSecondString];
```

Tell me if it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot...How did i miss that?? Anyhow thanks for the solution. I was totally blank.

Comment: Why are you creating an `NSString` using `stringWithFormat:` which is then passed to `NSMutableString`'s `initWithString:` when you could just use `NSMutableString`'s `initWithFormat:`?

Comment: Yes u were right. We can achieve the same by this way as well... NSMutableString *webServiceLinkWithResponses = [NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://lmsstaging.2xprime.com/services/ParticipantService.cfc?method=setVideoExamResults&student_id=10082&course_id=VRT_TRA&lesson=904&examtype=r&question_num=%@&ansValue=%@",yourFirstString,yourSecondString];

Answer (score 5):

The following will create an unretained `NSMutableString`:

```
NSMutableString *webServiceLinkWithResponses = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://lmsstaging.2xprime.com/services/ParticipantService.cfc?method=setVideoExamResults&student_id=10082&course_id=VRT_TRA&lesson=904&examtype=r&question_num=%@&ansValue=%@", stringOne, stringTwo];
```

If you need it to be retained simply use `[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"..."]`:

```
NSMutableString *webServiceLinkWithResponses = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://lmsstaging.2xprime.com/services/ParticipantService.cfc?method=setVideoExamResults&student_id=10082&course_id=VRT_TRA&lesson=904&examtype=r&question_num=%@&ansValue=%@", stringOne, stringTwo];
```

Do you really need it to be a mutable string, are you going to change it once it has been created?  If not simply change the `NSMutableString` to `NSString`, e.g. (this returns an autoreleased `NSString`, use `[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:]` if you need it retained):

```
NSString *webServiceLinkWithResponses = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://lmsstaging.2xprime.com/services/ParticipantService.cfc?method=setVideoExamResults&student_id=10082&course_id=VRT_TRA&lesson=904&examtype=r&question_num=%@&ansValue=%@", stringOne, stringTwo];
```

Answer (score 2):

My way would be:

```
NSMutableString *webServiceLinkWithResponses = [[[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://lmsstaging.2xprime.com/services/ParticipantService.cfc?method=setVideoExamResults&student_id=10082&course_id=VRT_TRA&lesson=904&examtype=r&question_num=%@&ansValue=%@",yourFirstString,yourSecondString] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

According to a hint from [dreamlax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10320/dreamlax) you can also use:

```
NSMutableString *webServiceLinkWithResponses = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://lmsstaging.2xprime.com/services/ParticipantService.cfc?method=setVideoExamResults&student_id=10082&course_id=VRT_TRA&lesson=904&examtype=r&question_num=%@&ansValue=%@", stringOne, stringTwo];
```

Comment: Alternatively, skip the `mutableCopy`/`autorelease` and just use `[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:]`